# CORS error only when I use endpoint with basic auth

Tags: javascript, axios, cors

I have a server on which cors is configured. I can access regular endpoints calmly without any errors, but I have problems with basic auth endpoints. I make the following request to the server:

```
axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL + "/api/admin",{}, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(`${login}:${password}`)
      }
})
```

As a result I get this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/admin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Once again I repeat that with the rest of the endpoint I do not get such an error.

I tried using a proxy in my package.json file that solved the problem but not as much as I would like in the future it will cause other problems and I would like to do without the proxy.

Comment: How is your CORS setup? Can you also share some code displaying this.

Comment: public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    }

Comment: what happens if you change the mapping to either `("*")` or `(/**/*)` and how are the routes that are not getting the CORS error structured are they longer or shorter?

Comment: This really should be tagged for springboot or whatever your backend is.  This has nothing to do with react or javascript

Comment: You also should post the headers that would have the CORS responses in them

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.allowedOrigins("*")` to fix this

> ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ...

```java
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) { 
  registry.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedMethods("*")
    .allowedOrigins("*");
}
```

Comment: I tried adding alowedOrigins, alowCredentials It didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `.allowedHeaders` too?

Comment: yes i did it like this:
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowCredentials(true);
    }

Comment: Just put `*` inside these parameter.

Comment: I did it, it just didn't copy well.